# how many background threads are running after starting C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading

I used unordered_map and I started 3 worker threads in my C++ program. But when I used gdb to run my code, I found the following GDB debug info frequently and continually were showing up:

```
[New Thread 0x2aaac3dc6700 (LWP 4709)]
[Thread 0x2aaac3dc6700 (LWP 4709) exited]
[New Thread 0x2aaac3dc6700 (LWP 4710)]
[Thread 0x2aaac3dc6700 (LWP 4710) exited]
[New Thread 0x2aaac3dc6700 (LWP 4711)]
[Thread 0x2aaac3dc6700 (LWP 4711) exited]
 .....................
```

How could so many threads were created and quickly destroyed, were there background threads for garbage collection of obsoleted objects(just like Java), I doubt if the unordered_map object caused so many threads to do clean for it.

Comment: This is a C++ implementation-specific issue. The reference to gdb means that this is linux. There are no background execution threads that are started by glibc or libstdc++. Perhaps this is sometihng that's happening in some library you're linking with.

Comment: Do you see the same amount of threads when not checking from gdb but on OS level instead ?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your program! Present a [mcve] so we can rule it out. Though you already seem to have done ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think you guys are wrong. If there were no BackGround threads, how could I have 50+ threads, when I used the follows command to watch: ps -T -P $pid.  I mean without GDB, I still could see 50+ threads, but I only started 3 threads.

Comment: Most likely, your program itself keeps creating and destroying threads, perhaps through some bug or misunderstanding on your part. Just using `std::unordered_map` doesn't cause threads to be created. You can verify this easily - write a sample program that, say, just adds and removes an element to the map in a loop, and check how many threads it creates.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you! but it's weird, I just created three threads, i.e I just called function pthread_create 3 times, and there was no loop.

Comment: Should you require further assistance, prepare a [mcve]. I, for one, can't help with code I can't see.

Comment: @Jack We have no way of knowing, without seeing your [mcve]. Not sure how we can be "wrong" for requesting one; you surely know how this site works by now.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik _"The reference to gdb means that this is linux."_ No, it could be Windows, or (less likely) macOS, or any of a number of other systems. I suggest consulting [this list of platforms supported by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html) to educate yourself more on the toolchain.